# Thoughts of Allah while using the restroom

Tags: kufr, waswasa

As far as I know, it is not allowed to talk about Allah while in the toilet. However, sometimes thoughts about Allah pop into my head one way or another, and I don't know if it is a sin. I don't say these thoughts out loud and I try not to think about it, but sometimes I forget that I am in the toilet. Q: Are these thoughts sinful and do they fall under the category of kufr? The fact is that I suffer from terrible waswas about whether I have committed kufr or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a sin to have remembrance of Allah, even if you are in the toilet.

From https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9286/can-you-take-allahs-name-in-the-bathroom :

> The scholars differentiated between the two types of dhikr. They said that it is makruh to remember Allah on the tongue (by speaking) in the bathroom and glorify Allah in that place. With regard to remembering Allah in one's heart, they said that this is not makuh and there is nothing wrong with it.

Read the entire linked page for more information that might be helpful to you.

Don't feel worried about having remembrance of Allah. It's a good thing! *"Oh you who believe! Remember Allah with much remembrance!"* (Qur'an, 33:41)